# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) Django

Tags: python, django, angular

I'm trying to do an endpoint API. And for that, i'm using django.

My url in `urls.py` is :

```
path('tutorials/', tutorial_list_test.as_view()),
```

and my `views.py` is like

```
class tutorial_list_test(GuestOnlyView, FormView):
    print("test");
    @api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
    def tutorial_list(self):
        request = self.request;
        if request.method == 'POST':
            alldata=request.POST
            username = alldata.get("username", "0")
            print("POST name: " + username)
            return Response('The tutorial does not exist', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

But when i'm doing a request, i have everytime the same error "`Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /accounts/tutorials/`"

So I did some research, and I could see several proposed solutions.
The first was to use csrf_exempt but it's not working for me:

```
path('tutorials/', csrf_exempt(tutorial_list_test.as_view())),
```

And it's the same for all the methods I used. Even if I remove this line from my settings.py, nothing changes

```
  #  django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

To test, I use Postman, but even using my angular front end, it does the same.

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('username', this.username_signup);

this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/tutorials/', formData)
.map((data: Response) => {
  if (data !== null) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
}).subscribe(response => console.log(response))
```

I would like to know if you have any idea how I can do this.

Because I need to be able to access my Models, so not using a class and directly making a def is not an option, even if it works.

(I tried, effectively my requests pass, if I remove the class and my route is only linked to my def tutorial_list).
Thank you.

Comment: Have tried to print `alldata` just for debugging ? Try `request.data/request.body  instead of request.POST`

Comment: I don't understand `def tutorial_list(self)` inside a class-based view: this method will never get called, since your class-based view is a `FormView` so it will first call the `dispatch()` method (and all pre-defined methods). The `@api_view` decorator is for function-based views.

Comment: @dirkgroten actually thanks, it was one of the mistake, I had misunderstood how it works. But I would like to know, why I have Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) when using dispatch & form_valid in this case but not a normal  function-based views without class ? Because it's one of my problem

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
    def tutorial_list(self):
        # code
```

Comment: No, as said above, no matter what I do with csrf_exempt, it doesn't work, i have the same error.